# How to skip all validations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a regular Rails model with many validations. The model has a `skip_validations` column. When an object has `skip_validations: true`, I want to be able to update the object without running any validations.

Is there any way to do this without adding an `unless` option to every validation? -- (for example `unless: Proc.new { |obj| obj.skip_validations == true }`)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all the conditional validations together, as documented here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#grouping-conditional-validations

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  with_options unless: Proc.new { |obj| obj.skip_validations == true } do |obj|
    obj.validates :password, length: { minimum: 10 }
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a field deliberately to skip validations, you can pass `validate: false` to the `save` method.

Please take a look at [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save)

*P.S: Better to stay away from reinventing the wheel.*

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer (not recommended) is to overwrite the `valid?` method inside the model.

```
def valid?(*args)
  if self.skip_validations
    return true
  end
  super(args)
end
```